# Error: Cannot find module 'nx/presets/npm.json'

Tags: javascript, build, nrwl-nx

Working on a legacy application and this error popped up out of nowhere after not updating any packages or changing any of the build setup

```
Run lerna bootstrap
  lerna bootstrap
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    FORTAWESOME_AUTH_TOKEN: ***
    HST_AUTH_TOKEN: ***
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nx/presets/npm.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js
- /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/devkit-exports.js
- /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/@nrwl/devkit/index.js
- /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/dist/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at Workspaces.readNxJson (/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js:145:52)
    at readNxJson (/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/config/configuration.js:7:72)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/client/client.js:290:72)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js',
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/nx/src/devkit-exports.js',
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/node_modules/@nrwl/devkit/index.js',
    '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/17.9.1/x64/lib/node_modules/lerna/dist/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Node.js v17.9.1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I've tried updating nx in a million different ways which most solutions suggest, but that does nothing. Here is my nx.json

```
{
  "extends": "nx/presets/npm.json",
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "nx/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": [
          "dev",
          "build",
          "lint",
          "clean",
          "test",
          "compile",
          "setup",
          "format",
          "commitlint",
          "document",
          "storybook",
          "build-storybook"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "targetDependencies": {
    "build": [
      {
        "target": "build",
        "projects": "dependencies"
      }
    ]
  },
  "affected": {
    "defaultBase": "main"
  }
}
```

I updated nx, but no idea what else to attempt at this point since 0 configuration files were changed, so I don't even have anything to revert.

[https://nx.dev/core-features/automate-updating-dependencies#updating-nx`](https://nx.dev/core-features/automate-updating-dependencies#updating-nx%60)

Comment: I have the exact same issue with a legacy project that built fine 2 weeks ago but now is failing with the same error message but for Node 14. Did you ever find a solution? The interesting thing in my case is that the project does not even use NX, it uses Lerna.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue when switching from npm to pnpm.
Resolved the issue by removing "extends": "nx/presets/npm.json" from my nx.json file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by installing a local nx (`npm install nx`) inside the project.

Actually I already have a global nx installed, it does contain the file `/Users/my_user_name/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/nx/presets/npm.json`. However it cannot be found via `nx/presets/npm.json`.